# How can I overwrite a Class Object in C++ using the Assignment Operator, after the Object has already been initialized?

Tags: c++

I want to be able to do something like this

```
MyClass my_class;
vector<MyClass> my_vector; // Imagine this is already populated
my_class = my_vector[0];
```

I would imagine that I would need to write a assignment operator for MyClass like so

```
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& rhs);
```

I stepped through my program, and it didn't even run the assignment operator overload...

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: There is no element 0 to assign to `my_class` in the first place.

Comment: Don't say 'override' when you mean 'overwrite', and *vice versa.* They aren't the same thing.

Comment: You should design your classes, where possible, so that the compiler-provided assignment operator does what is required.

Comment: @NeilKirk, good point, i.e. the rule of zero http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator would have to be defined as a member function like this:

```
class MyClass {
...
public:
   MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& rhs) {
       ....
       return *this;
   }
};
```

Even if the vector were not populated, it should run the `MyClass::operator=` assignment operator. But then it would cause undefined behavior (segfault) when accessing `rhs`.

It it doesn't run the assignment operator, maybe it got optimized away, if optimizations are enabled when compiling, and `my_class` is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there's nothing wrong with your code (assuming indeed you're not accessing out-of-bounds when using `my_vector[0]`). The line `my_vector[0]` returns a `MyClass` object by reference, which is then being assigned in the next line

```
my_class = my_vector[0];
```

using the default `MyClass.operator=`. If you don't define a copy assignment operator, [the compiler defines one for you implicitly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator) (except in the case when you defined move semantics operators). The default assignment operator does a member-by-member copy (i.e., it invokes each member's assignment operator; for PODs, it just do a bit-wise copy).

> > I stepped through my program, and it didn't even run the assignment operator overload...

If you indeed declared and defined a copy assignment operator, then the compiler should invoke it. How did you test that it was not invoked?

Comment: I set a breakpoint on the assignment and stepped into it, it didn't run.

Comment: @Ricky can you then post a minimal example? Strip down the code to the minimal one that can reproduce the issue, then post it here.